Property of a family of simple polynomials related to the A329369

Let $a(n)$ be A329369 (i.e., number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dotsc,m\}$ with excedance set constructed by taking $m-i$ ($0 < i < m$) if $b(i-1) = 1$ where $b(k)b(k-1)\cdots b(1)b(0)$ ($0 \leqslant k < m-1$) is the binary expansion of $n$). Here

$$
a(2^m(2k+1)) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m+1}{j}a(2^jk), \\
a(0) = 1.
$$
We can also rewrite it as
$$
a(2k+1) = a(k), \\
a(2^m(2k+1)) = a(2^mk) + a(2^{m-1}(2k+1)) + a(2^{m-1}(4k+1))
$$

Let $R(n, x)$ be the family of polynomials such that

$$
R(2n+1, x) = xR(n, x), \\
R(2n, x) = x(R(n, x+1) - R(n, x)), \\
R(0, x) = x
$$

Let $b(n, m, q)$ be the family of integer sequences such that

$$
b(n, m, q) = \sum\limits_{i>0} a(2^m(2^{i-1} - 1) + q)[x^i]R(n, x).
$$
I conjecture that $$b(n, m, q) = a(2^mn + q).$$
I also conjecture that for $m>0$ we have
$$R(2^m(2k+1), x) = R(2^mk, x) + R(2^{m-1}(2k+1), x) + R(2^{m-1}(4k+1), x).$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
T(n, k) = my(A = 2*n+1, B, C, v1, v2); v1 = []; while(A > 0, B=valuation(A, 2); v1=concat(v1, B+1); A \= 2^(B+1)); v1 = Vecrev(v1); A = #v1; v2 = vector(A, i, 1); for(i=1, A-1, B = A-i; for(j=1, B, C = B-j+k+1; v2[j] = v2[j]*C^v1[B] - v2[j+1]*(C-1)^v1[B])); v2[1]
a(n) = T(n, 1)
R(n, x) = my(x = 'x, A = x); forstep(i=logint(n, 2), 0, -1, A = if(bittest(n, i), x*A, x*(subst(A, x, x+1) - A))); A
b(n, m, q) = my(x = 'x, A = valuation(n+1, 2), v1); v1 = Vecrev(R(n, x)/x^(A+1)); sum(i=1, #v1, v1[i]*a(2^m*(2^(i+A-1)-1)+q))
R1(n, x) = my(x = 'x); if(n == 0, x, if(n%2, x*R1(n\2, x), my(A = 1 << valuation(n\2, 2)); R1(n\2, x) + R1(n\2-A, x) + R1(n-A, x)))
test1(n, m, q) = b(n, m, q) == a(2^m*n + q)
test2(n) = R(n, x) == R1(n, x)

Is there a way to prove it?
